# Display post to another website

Tags: plugins

Is there any other way to display posts to another website aside from API and feed?

I have a wordpress site and I want the recents posts to display on external websites which is built on ROR and PHP (not a wordpress site).

**Example:**

Recent posts of abc.com will display on xyz.com.

Comment: 'Display post *to* another website'? Sorry, that's doesn't make sense. Do you mean *from* another website?

Comment: Hi @JacobPeattie, recent posts of abc.com will display on xyz.com.

Comment: That doesn’t help. Which one is you? Both?

Comment: Use any HTML parser, write a piece of code to publish the parsed content and set the cron job. But RSS is much more simpler as there are dozens of plugins and services for syndication.

Comment: Both. I have a wordpress site and I want the recent posts to displayed on my external website which is built on ROR.

Comment: Well you can get recent posts from the REST API or RSS. The rest seems to be something you’d do in ROR, not WordPress.

Comment: The easiest solution by far is the RSS feed, followed by direct DB access and the REST API. @jack why not just use the RSS feed?

Comment: Hi @bosco, I'm thinking maybe it can be done like embed where css styles is included. It feels like redundant where I have to style it again in ROR.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at. There are a couple means that come to mind - I'll throw together an answer a little later